Connecting to new SQL Server Express
I'm migrating a smallish MS Access database to SQL Server. I've installed new instance of SQL Server 2022 Express on a Win10 box.
Setup was done pretty much with all the defaults. Processed database backend through SSMA. All tables seem to be migrated successfully. Data is visible on the server box.
Now I'm attempting to connect from a separate machine on the domain network. I cannot connect via Access and just trying to establish connection via ODBC at this point. Continually getting failed connection tests. It seems to be an networking issue.
I'm sure it's a basic problem I'm missing with the connection. I've been beating this up for several days. I sincerely appreciate ANY assistance.
In Server Config Mgr, protocol set to use port 1433. I have checked firewall. Port 1433 is opened. All machines are domain joined. I can connect to the server via RDP. I can map a network drive on the server (just to prove to myself that I can access the server).
All services appear to be running. I have multiple ODBC drivers installed on client... none seem to work.
Screenshots below.  server name: RWP02  db: genysis
Server services:

Server remote connections:

Server ports:

Server firewall:

Client driver list:

Client server select:

Client connect error:


Just to be clear: does the odbc test succeed on the host machine? Are you testing with the same domain user on all machines? Is the server in windows authentication mode, sql mode, or mixed?

Have you tried connecting using the IP address instead of the machine name of the SQL Server?

Can you connect from your client machine via ssms?

did you restart the service after changing ports? I usually set the port number into the Dynamic port textbox

Remove the instance name and just connect to RWP02.  The instance name requires SQL Browser to be running and accessible on UDP port 1434.  You configured the instance to listen on 1433, which is the default port for SQL Server so that's unnecessary.
If that doesn't work verify name resolution and TCP/IP connectivity with the powershell command:
test-netconnection RWP02 -Port 1433

Thanks David. I changed the server to just RWP02 and still get same connection error (server does not exist or access denied)
